# Can I freeze fruit shrub?

Tags: freezing, fruit, storage

I am about to make some fruit shrub for use in drinks. I have clear instructions and I understand that it will keep safely for 6 months in the fridge (barring signs of spoilage). However, I have so much fruit right now that I'm wondering if I can make a larger quantity and freeze it in smaller batches once it's fermented, defrosting as I go for use throughout the year. Any reason not to? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason not to.

You may notice slight flavor changes over time, but that’s also true if you are storing the shrub in the fridge or preserved sugary fruit preparations at room temperature. The high sugar content will influence the freezing behavior, for example it may not solidify completely, but if you use the appropriate containers, this won’t matter at all. For food safety, freezing is an excellent choice.